# Geodesic equation using 4-momenta

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, momentum, coordinate-systems, geodesics

I know the geodesic equation in the form
$$\frac{d^2X^\mu}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha}\frac{dX^\nu}{d\lambda} \frac{dX^\alpha}{d\lambda} = 0,$$
where $\lambda$ is a parametrization of the curve $X^\mu(\lambda)$.

However, in the textbook I also see a formulation of the geodesic equation using the 4-momentum $P^\mu$,
$$
\frac{d X^{\nu}}{d \tau} \nabla_{\nu} \frac{d X^{\mu}}{d \tau}=P^{\nu} \nabla_{\nu} P^{\mu}=0.
$$

It is not clear to me how we arrive at this formulation. It seems that we simply switched out $\lambda$ to $\tau$ — but why are we able to do that?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674564/25301

Comment: Is $\tau$ the proper time?

Comment: Yes, it is the proper time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geodesic equation can be written equivalently when $X$ is parametrized with proper time:
$$
\frac{d^2X^\mu}{d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha}\frac{dX^\nu}{d\tau} \frac{dX^\alpha}{d\tau} = 0\,.
$$
Here, $\tau\mapsto X^\mu(\tau)$ is a world line whose four velocity is $\frac{dX^\mu}{d\tau}$ and whose acceleration is $\frac{d^2X^\mu}{d\tau^2}\,.$

Now suppose we have a four-velocity field $U^\mu$ at every point of space time (or at least around the world line $X^\mu$) such that
$$
\frac{dX^\mu(\tau)}{d\tau}=U^\mu(X^\mu(\tau))\,.
$$
By the chain rule
$$\tag{1}
\frac{d^2X^\mu(\tau)}{d\tau^2}=\frac{dX^\mu(\tau)}{d\tau}\partial_\nu U^\mu(X^\mu(\tau))=(U^\nu\partial_\nu U^\mu)(X^\mu(\tau))\,.
$$
Dropping the clumsy argument $X^\mu(\tau)$ the geodesic equation then implies
$$
U^\nu\partial_\nu U^\mu+\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha}U^\nu U^\alpha=U^\nu\nabla_\nu U^\mu=0.
$$
Four momentum $P^\mu$ is just rest mass $m_0$ times four velocity $U^\mu\,.$ This does not alter the geodesic equation.

Few remarks.

- In curved space time $\frac{d^2X^\mu}{d\tau^2}$ is not the four acceleration. Since by (1) it is $U^\nu\partial_\nu U^\mu$ which does not transform as a tensor due to the partial derivative there.
- The correct way of defining  ***four acceleration*** is
  $$\tag{2}
  A^\mu\equiv\frac{d^2X^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha}\frac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}\frac{dX^\alpha}{d\tau}\,.
  $$
  As above this is seen to be equal to $U^\nu\nabla_\nu U^\mu\,.$
  This is the covariant derivative of $U$ in the direction of $U\,.$
  Some authors also write $\dot U^\mu$ for $A^\mu$
  and the shortest form of the geodesic equation is
  $$
  \boxed{A^\mu=0\,.}
  $$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It is super clear.

Comment: One a second note - can this equation be used for photons? Or is it only valid for particles with mass? (since the proper time is zero along the photon worldline)

Comment: Indeed, the geodesic equations hold only for *timelike* world lines, exactly because these are the world lines that have a non zero proper time. This does however not mean that only timelike geodesics exist. Another related post is [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511602/why-do-we-know-that-light-must-follow-a-geodesic). In short: if photons are only subject to gravity and otherwise unperturbed they follow lightlike geodesics.