# Generalised Geodesic equation for forces

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, differential-geometry, geodesics

im wondering if there is a general geodesic equation that describes the forces and how they act. For example I started off with the original nieve derivation of the geodesic equation:
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}e_\tau=\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}e_\mu\right)=0$$
Using the product rule
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}e_\mu\right)=\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{de_\mu}{d\tau}$$
Im not too sure on this next step, however if we imagine an internal space controlled by a paramater $\theta$ can we do the chain rule on this to give
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{de_\mu}{d\tau}=\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}\frac{de_\mu}{d\theta}$$
Rewriting gives the following
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}\frac{de_\mu}{d\theta}=\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}\frac{de_\mu}{d\theta}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$
Where the $\frac{d e_\mu} {d\theta}$ is how the basis vectors change when moving along the internal space. So this can be interpreted as a connection.
$$\frac{d e_\mu} {d\theta}=F_\mu^\alpha e_\alpha$$
Plugging this back into the equation gives
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}e_\mu+\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}F_\mu^\alpha \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}e_\alpha=0$$
Rewriting the summed indicies
$$\left(\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}F_\alpha^\mu\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}\right)e_\mu=0$$
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}F_\alpha^\mu\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}=0$$
If $\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}= -\frac{q}{m}$ Then we get the following.
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}-\frac{q}{m}F_\alpha^\mu\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau}=0$$
Which is the form of an charged particle moving in an electromagnetic field
Is this derivation valid and am I allowed to do that suspect step?

Comment: $\tau$ is proper time ? What is $e_\tau$ and $e_\mu$ ? Not sure if [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691349/geodesic-equation-using-4-momenta/) helps.

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified $e_\tau$ is the basis vector moving along the proper time and $e_\mu$ is the positional basis vector