# Would gravity pulling person toward Earth change if velocity of Earth changes?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

So I was reading the Albert Einstein's theory of how gravity works. From my understanding, the more mass an object has, the more space-time around it it bends. All objects travels in completely straight lines,but they eventually end up attracted by some other object, as the other object bended space-time around, so the originally straight line the other object is traveling is now pointing towards the first object.

But how would that explain gravity? Because even though I am now on Earth, completely stationary, I am still being pulled toward Earth. This in my uneducated eyes can be explained only by the fact, that our planet, even entire galaxy is traveling at quite high speed, so even if I now feel stationary, I am actually drifting through space. And if the space-time is now curved around me, the velocity of me, in combination with curved space-time, is now pulling me toward earth. That would mean that gravity is changing with velocity, and at completely stationary velocity in space, gravity just won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes matter travel along geodesics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92250/)

Comment: Even when you consider yourself stationary you are moving in the time dimension, and it's the movement in time that causes you to accelerate.

Comment: That makes sense. But would gravity change with speed? For example if our whole galaxy suddenly accelerated, would gravity on Earth be stronger?

Comment: a few things to note:  1. it's spacertime that's curved, not just space.  2.  By sitting on the surface of the earth, you are not freely falling, and your experience of weight is explained, in general relativity, by the force of the ground on you preventing you from going on that freely falling path.