# What are the main issues with gauge theories of gravity?

Tags: gravity, symmetry, yang-mills, gauge

From what I understand, the obvious problems with a gravity being a posed as a gauge theory of the Lorentz group are the residual tetrad fields having no obvious gauge theoretic interpretation, as well as this group simply not being the full set of diffeomorphisms. Gauging the full Poincare group appears to not only consider the full set of spacetime isometries but also provides a description of the tetrad fields as gauge potentials for the translation symmetries in the group.

What are the remaining obstacles to a convincing gauge theory of gravity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gravity as a gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71476/)

Comment: See also:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/diffm-as-a-gauge-group-and-local-observables-in-theories-with-gravity
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/argument-about-fallacy-of-diffm-being-a-gauge-group-for-general-relativity
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46324/to-which-extent-is-general-relativity-a-gauge-theory
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339699/coupling-fermions-with-gravity